Apache DBCP 1.4 || Idle connection timeout in 15 min configuration with Java based application
We are doing GOS oracle database Migration for Java Based application.
In Java application , we are using apache DBCP 1.4 to connect to oracle database.
Now GOS ,comes with the limitation that Idle DB connection will get timeout after 15 min , With the new config on Oracle, applications will see a connection in the pool that has been killed by Oracle, resulting in an error of "Unable to get connection".
Now, As part of resolution ,
The connection pool parameters in apache DBCP need to updated to make the connection pool idle timeout less than the Oracle timeout.
So, I have updated below params
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 840000 MS ~ 14 min
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis : 60000 MS ~ 1 min
Refer: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html
Any suggestion , Apart from above 2 params any other things needs to get configure as apache DBCP 1.4 has limited params than Apache DBCP2
Idle connection should get evicted after 15 min

What is the actual error message?

did not receive any error
